# Retrieving Maven Artifact from Repository using Maven Java API

Tags: java, api, maven, maven-plugin, aether

If I have a Maven Artifact information (GroupId, ArtifactId, Version) how can I programmatically (using Java) retrieve that Artifact from my local repository?

Specifically, I need to be able to connect to the Maven Repository and create/retrieve a org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact so I can retrieve the file associated with the Artifact.

I have looked into m2e source code, but the MavenImpl.java (which provides Artifact resolution) is way more complex than what I need and it is difficult to understand how the connection to the repository works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll probably want to look at [Aether](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.aether). See the [Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether) for examples.

Comment: Note for anyone looking for this: Aether has been adopted by the apache foundation and renamed to maven-resolver: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.resolver

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a URL from the given information and download the file (note, replace the `'.'` in the `<groupId>` with `'/'`):

```
<repositoryUrl>/<groupId>/<artifactId>/<version>/<artifactId>-<version>.<type>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how we do it in [jcabi-aether](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aether/):

```
final File repo = this.session.getLocalRepository().getBasedir();
final Collection<Artifact> deps = new Aether(this.getProject(), repo).resolve(
  new DefaultArtifact("junit", "junit-dep", "", "jar", "4.10"),
  JavaScopes.RUNTIME
);
```

Give it a list of remote repositories, a location of a local repo, and Maven coordinates of the artifact. As the name shows, the library uses [Apache Aether](http://www.sonatype.org/aether) from Sonatype.

Comment: Hi! I try to use jcabi-aether outside of maven project as visible here: http://aether.jcabi.com/index.html, but I always getting a  compile exception: Error:(22, 25) java: cannot access org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject
  class file for org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject not found. If I include maven-core, I get other exceptions. Why? Is this project still maintained?