# Retrieve/Upload artifacts from/to maven repository using c#

Tags: c#, .net, maven

I need to access Maven repository(upload and retrieve artifacts) from my C# code?
What are the available C# libraries to get this done.

I think I probably need c# equivalent for the answers posted here
[Retrieving Maven Artifact from Repository using Maven Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674537/retrieving-maven-artifact-from-repository-using-maven-java-api)

Google/Stackoverflow results mostly in java libraries to do the same

Comment: Why do you need C# code to access a Maven repository? Why not using Java code for it?

Comment: This is small part of a bigger c# code base, so I cant use Java code

Comment: So why do you need access to maven repository which usually contains only Java code? So you have to giva via Aether or check to see if you find code related to [nuGet](http://www.nuget.org/) which should contain code to retrieve artifacts from a repository in particular from a Nexus which supports nuGet.